# Struts2 <s:iterator> random duplicating values

Tags: java, jpa, struts2, eclipselink, derby

Technology used : Struts2 , JPA (EclipseLink) , Apache Derby Database.

My project is on *image hosting* and I have `UserEntity` (parent) configured to contain reference to `ImageEntity`.

I have a session variable called `userEntity` which is the User object fetched on login. A JSP page `myUploads.jsp` to use the List in user object and display all values. I have used the struts iterator tag `<s:iterator>` to loop the `List`.

Problem :

RANDOM duplication of rows by `<s:iterator>`.

Note : I have check the database , and it has no duplication, it can be observed that the duplicated entry share the same image ID.

**JSP CODE:**

```
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Comments</th>
                <th>Link</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Delete image</th>
                <th>Share details</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <s:iterator value="#session.userEntity.images" var="image">

                <s:url id="imageURL" action="myUploads" >
                    <s:param name="imageID" value="#image.id"></s:param>
                </s:url>

                <s:url id="deleteImageURL" action="deleteImage" method="deleteImage">
                    <s:param name="imageID" value="#image.id"></s:param>
                </s:url>
                 <tr>
                        <td><s:property value="#image.name"/></td>
                        <td><s:property value="#image.comments"/></td>
                        <td><s:a href="%{imageURL}" cssClass="linkStyle">
                                <s:property value="#image.imageName"/>
                            </s:a></td>
                        <td>
                           <s:a href="%{imageURL}" cssClass="linkStyle"> <img width="200" height="200" src="<s:url action='ImageAction'><s:param name='imageID' value="#image.id"></s:param></s:url>" /> </s:a></td>
                        <td>
                            <s:a href="%{deleteImageURL}" cssClass="linkStyle">
                                Delete
                            </s:a>   </td>
                        <td>
                           <s:if test="%{#image.shares != null}">
                               <ul> 
                               <s:iterator value="#image.shares" var="share">
                                   <li><s:property value="#share.fullName"/></li>
                               </s:iterator>
                               </ul>
                           </s:if>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

            </s:iterator>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Generated HTML code (view source on run):**

```
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Comments</th>
                <th>Link</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Delete image</th>
                <th>Share details</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

                ROW 1 : imageID=151
                    <tr>
                        <td>sun</td>
                        <td>sun set</td>
                        <td><a href="/ImageHosting5.7/myUploads.action?imageID=151" class="linkStyle">
                                Sunset.jpg
                            </a></td>
                        <td>
                           <a href="/ImageHosting5.7/myUploads.action?imageID=151" class="linkStyle"> <img width="200" height="200" src="/ImageHosting5.7/ImageAction.action?imageID=151" /> </a></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/ImageHosting5.7/deleteImage!deleteImage.action?imageID=151" class="linkStyle">
                                Delete
                            </a>   </td>
                        <td>

                               <ul> 

                                   <li>b</li>

                               </ul>

                        </td>
                    </tr>


             ROW 2 : imageID=151
                    <tr>
                        <td>sun</td>
                        <td>sun set</td>
                        <td><a href="/ImageHosting5.7/myUploads.action?imageID=151" class="linkStyle">
                                Sunset.jpg
                            </a></td>
                        <td>
                           <a href="/ImageHosting5.7/myUploads.action?imageID=151" class="linkStyle"> <img width="200" height="200" src="/ImageHosting5.7/ImageAction.action?imageID=151" /> </a></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/ImageHosting5.7/deleteImage!deleteImage.action?imageID=151" class="linkStyle">
                                Delete
                            </a>   </td>
                        <td>

                               <ul> 

                                   <li>b</li>

                               </ul>

                        </td>
                    </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This happens randomly for any image, but the same repetition is reflected all the times,
that is if image A is repeated once, and I upload image B which is not repeated, the `myUploads.jsp` will have image A twice .

BUT when I delete the repeated image ONCE the other copy gets bugged (cannot download, cannot view) which implies the LIST IS NOT REDUNDANT, but the Name and comment fields remain, and one image A exists

> List.remove() API quote:
>   Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present (optional operation).

e.g.

another view source after a few more image uploads (where other images are not repeated)

```
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Comments</th>
                <th>Link</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Delete image</th>
                <th>Share details</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
      ROW 1 : imageID=151
                    <tr>
                        <td>sun</td>
                        <td>sun set</td>
                        <td><a href="/ImageHosting5.7/myUploads.action?imageID=151" class="linkStyle">
                                Sunset.jpg
                            </a></td>
                        <td>
                           <a href="/ImageHosting5.7/myUploads.action?imageID=151" class="linkStyle"> <img width="200" height="200" src="/ImageHosting5.7/ImageAction.action?imageID=151" /> </a></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/ImageHosting5.7/deleteImage!deleteImage.action?imageID=151" class="linkStyle">
                                Delete
                            </a>   </td>
                        <td>

                               <ul> 

                                   <li>b</li>

                               </ul>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
        ROW 2 : imageID=151
                    <tr>
                        <td>sun</td>
                        <td>sun set</td>
                        <td><a href="/ImageHosting5.7/myUploads.action?imageID=151" class="linkStyle">
                                Sunset.jpg
                            </a></td>
                        <td>
                           <a href="/ImageHosting5.7/myUploads.action?imageID=151" class="linkStyle"> <img width="200" height="200" src="/ImageHosting5.7/ImageAction.action?imageID=151" /> </a></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/ImageHosting5.7/deleteImage!deleteImage.action?imageID=151" class="linkStyle">
                                Delete
                            </a>   </td>
                        <td>

                               <ul> 

                                   <li>b</li>

                               </ul>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
           ROW 3 : imageID=152
                    <tr>
                        <td>abc</td>
                        <td>aaa</td>
                        <td><a href="/ImageHosting5.7/myUploads.action?imageID=152" class="linkStyle">
                                Blue hills.jpg
                            </a></td>
                        <td>
                           <a href="/ImageHosting5.7/myUploads.action?imageID=152" class="linkStyle"> <img width="200" height="200" src="/ImageHosting5.7/ImageAction.action?imageID=152" /> </a></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/ImageHosting5.7/deleteImage!deleteImage.action?imageID=152" class="linkStyle">
                                Delete
                            </a>   </td>
                        <td>

                               <ul> 

                               </ul>

                        </td>
                    </tr>



                ROW 4 : imageID=153
                    <tr>
                        <td>apng</td>
                        <td>aaa</td>
                        <td><a href="/ImageHosting5.7/myUploads.action?imageID=153" class="linkStyle">
                                A PNG IMAGE.PNG
                            </a></td>
                        <td>
                           <a href="/ImageHosting5.7/myUploads.action?imageID=153" class="linkStyle"> <img width="200" height="200" src="/ImageHosting5.7/ImageAction.action?imageID=153" /> </a></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/ImageHosting5.7/deleteImage!deleteImage.action?imageID=153" class="linkStyle">
                                Delete
                            </a>   </td>
                        <td>

                               <ul> 

                                   <li>b</li>

                               </ul>

                        </td>
                    </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Entity class for `Image`:**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id; --------> UNIQUE

private String name;
private String comments;

@ManyToOne
private UserEntity userEntity;

private String imagePath;    
private String imageName;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private List<UserEntity> shares; // list of owner IDs

private Boolean publicShare; // isShared
```

Usage of the method and the method that adds to list

NOTE : The method is used 'only once' as spotted in the image added below. So, I got no bugged code that may add

[image]

**the `addImage()` method:**

```
private boolean addImage()
{       
    DatabaseService db;       
    try {
        db = new DatabaseService();           

        // get userEntity from session
        Map sessionMap = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        userEntity = (UserEntity) sessionMap.get("userEntity");

        // save image to file system
        String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/images");          
        File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.uploadFileFileName);
        FileUtils.copyFile(this.uploadFile, fileToCreate);

        // make imageEntity
        imageEntity = new ImageEntity();
        imageEntity.setName(name);
        imageEntity.setComments(comments);
        imageEntity.setUserEntity(userEntity);

        try {
            if(!userShare.isEmpty())
             imageEntity.setShares(new DatabaseService().findUserEntitysByUsernames(users));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", e);
        }

        imageEntity.setImagePath(fileToCreate.getAbsolutePath());
        imageEntity.setImageName(fileToCreate.getName());           
        db.persist(imageEntity);           
        userEntity.addToImages(imageEntity);           

        // update userEntity                      
        userEntity = (UserEntity) db.merge(userEntity);

        // update sessionMap
        sessionMap.put("userEntity", userEntity);

        // notify share
        if( ! imageEntity.getShares().isEmpty())
        {               
            // init mail
            SendMailService sendMailService = new SendMailService();
            sendMailService.setBody("Image is shared with you");
            sendMailService.setSubject("DJVT IMAGE HOSTING");

            for (UserEntity ue : imageEntity.getShares()) {
                sendMailService.setTo(ue.getEmailid());
            }

            sendMailService.sendMail();
        }           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("img upload failed" + e.toString());
    }

    return true; // success
}
```

How do I solve my bug, and by the way what are your opinions about this bug (or error if I am making silly mistakes)?

I logged out and logged in to my application and the duplication was gone once.

Comment: Show us the action, the objects that are being returned to the client, and the test you are doing to prove that there is not any duplication before sending the data to the view.

Comment: some problem in my session variable .. ill check it  properly and get back

Comment: Without more information it'll be impossible to help.

Comment: i loggedout and logged in to my application and the duplication was gone once .. i am my self confused :(

Comment: Might be problem of database query if you are using joins,in that case there will be duplicate entry

Answer (score 0):

> How do i solve my bug , and by the way what are your opinions about
> this bug(or error if i am making silly mistakes)

The problems that you are sharing a collection that you iterate in the session. So the other actions may *update* this collection before the result is executed. To check this you could put [`BeforeResult` annotation](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/before-result-annotation.html) on method where you could check for duplicates. Make sure you have [`annotationWorkflow` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/annotation-workflow-interceptor.html) that replaces `workflow` interceptor on the stack.

Other possibilities could be if you change the default theme to

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple"/>
```

in the `struts.xml` or use `css_xhtml` theme.